# Team City + Gallio runs tests, but results are not shown

Tags: teamcity, gallio

We recently updated to Visual Studio 2010, and as part of our upgrade we started using Gallio 3.2 prerelease builds. Everything runs fine in Visual Studio (through resharper) but I'm having problems with TeamCity integration. The tests seem to run during TeamCity builds just fine (our build takes long enough to run all our tests), but the tests are not showing up in TeamCity's test area. Here is the test target from our NANT build file (this hasn't changed in our upgrade at all). Is there a trick to getting the tests to show up in TeamCity or is this something that's broken in the latest builds of Gallio?

`<target name="runTests">`
`<gallio`
`result-property="exitCode"`
`failonerror="false">`
`<runner-extension value="TeamCityExtension,Gallio.TeamCityIntegration" />`
`<assemblies>`
`<include name="..\Source\Tests\${testProject}\bin\Debug\${testProject}.dll" />`
`</assemblies>`
`</gallio>`
`</target>`

Comment: I've got the same problem, using msbuild. Anyone got a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `echo-results="true"` like this:

```
<target name="runTests">
<gallio
result-property="exitCode"
echo-results="true"
failonerror="false">
<runner-extension value="TeamCityExtension,Gallio.TeamCityIntegration" />
<assemblies>
<include name="..\Source\Tests\${testProject}\bin\Debug\${testProject}.dll" />
</assemblies>
</gallio>
<fail if="${exitCode != '0'}" >One or more tests failed. Please check the log for more details</fail>    
</target>
```